# Every time i switch tap from a game to anything else it gives me black screen and it takes time to switch

Tags: windows

In my new PC this happens when i had my old laptop it used to switch fast but i am worried that i am missing something on this new PC
Specs:
GTX 1070 8gp
Icore 5 7500
16gp ram
120gp ssd
1tp hard disc 
730 power suppler thermaltake

Answer (score 2):

That's normal when you are playing using full screen. If you want switch from a game to anything else fast try using borderless screen option in the video settings of each game that you play.

Comment: I will sure try to do that, thank you so much